# Disks slow down after a while in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, performance

I run Ubuntu 18.04.4 (lubuntu) on Dell Latitude E7440 with i5, 16GB mem, two disks: SSD 250GB (Samsung 850 EVO mSATA) + HDD 500GB (Seagate ST500LM021).
I started to feel it gets somehow slow over time. I tried to observe and found disk writes slow down significantly after some time since starting the machine. For checking the speed, I run:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=[a file on SSD/HDD] bs=1M count=128
```

The HDD is with NTFS, SDD with ext4, both less than 75% full.

Shortly after start or reboot, the speeds are about 100MB/s for HDD and about 400MB/s for SSD but when I try again after a while (20min is enough), HDD is at some 300kb/s and SSD 5MB/s or even slower. No matter if I use the laptop meanwhile, it falls to that slow even if I only log in and let it alone.
Laptop is socket-powered (via dock), during the test no other "my" apps (=intentionally launched by myself) are running, top shows average load under 1%, CPU freq. is always above 2GHz, does not seem to overheat, free -m says:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16048         890       12156         429        3002       13550
Swap:          8191           0        8191
```

Disk reads seem not to be affected, both HDD and SSD are at about 5GB/s after the start as well as later (dd if=[that file] of=/dev/null bs=1M count=128).
As *both* disks get that slow, I do not think it is a disk issue (that would affect only one disk) but cannot find out what else to check (and it might not be the single issue but at least this is something which I consider not good anyway). Any hints?

Comment: Have you seen [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 18.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/528072)

Comment: Yes, I checked smartctl for both drives, nothing suspicious. (anyway, as it immediately turns OK after reset, I won't expect S.M.A.R.T. to show something bad).

Comment: Could be your PC is throttling due to overheating, either at CPU- or RAM-bus-level. In Speccy, what are the temps for both drives? With the mSATA in, it can feel a bit cramped inside a Latitude chassis.

Comment: I would try to use a Live Linux DVD with a different version and/or distribution just to check if this behavior is caused by software.

Comment: @Didier Good suggestion, however temperature usually only affects the CPU and the SSD. In my experience HDDs can still work even if they are right before "melting away". In any way the temperature hypothesis can be checked easily: If the speed is reduced reboot the PC and check if this restores the speed. If it restores the speed for again ~20 minutes temperature problems are unlikely.

Comment: @Robert it's the fact that it happens after 20 minutes give or take that made me think of a temperature problem, but you're right, an HDD would keep on working until it fails completely, except it wouldn't just slow down. For me, it's either a temp issue, or some system I/0 cache that gets saturated and isn't cleared automatically. EDIT: how much space have you dedicated to swap, Davidob?

Comment: CPU temp is below 50°C, freq does not drop (mentioned above). The 20 minutes is not exact (but hard to measure). Swap is 8G.

Comment: When I catch the slowdown, I can see gradual decrease by running the dd test over and over, the speed keeps dropping down to hundreds of kb/s. Immediate reboot helps. Logging off+on without reboot does not help.

Comment: Can I somehow observe system resources like IO handles, cache usage, ... whatever other? ps -ax does not show anything I can recognize as bad, top does not show something weird neither (at least to what I can judge)

Comment: If you safely unmount the NTFS drive ( [Command line equivalent to “Safely remove drive”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387129) ) does the SSD speed up again? The answer to [Speed of HDD getting extremly slow](https://askubuntu.com/q/1176252) was "I changed the NTFS drive to EXT4."

Comment: After unmounting the HDD NTFS drive, SSD with etx4 speeds up but not to the original level, about to a half. After mounting the NTFS drive back again, that drive it is at its original speed but drops after a while as before.

Comment: Now a new observation: write speed of both disks dropped again (SSD 3.5MB/s, HDD 300kB/s). Unmounted the HDD (with NTFS), but the SSD remained at 3.5MB.s. Rebooted, SSD is at 400MB/s, HDD at 100MB/s. So it seems NTFS was not the issue.

Comment: Shot in the dark: last time I had a slow drive (decades ago), I found out it was not using DMA for access. Not sure this kind of thing can happen in 2020 but in any case it could be useful to explore the drive parameters with `hdparm`.

Comment: SATA sort of implies DMA if I remeber well. Anyway, hdparm says both drives are set udma6